# How to fix docker on create containers

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-container

I'm trying to create a container on Docker using Linux
I'm trying to run

`docker run hello-world`

And I get an error

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI
> runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container
> process: error during container init: error jailing process inside
> rootfs: pivot_root .: invalid argument: unknown.

Unfortunately, my system does not have **apt**
or **dpkg**
This is why I am limited in use, I have full root access on my system
my system info
`Linux localhost 5.13.x #1 SMP Fri Apr 14 00:13:58 CST 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I've tried to run `docked` and these are the outputs

> root@localhost:/volume1/.@root # dockerd ...
> WARN[2023-06-08T19:55:02.790387966+03:00] Failed to find ip6tables:
> exec: "ip6tables": executable file not found in $PATH
> WARN[2023-06-08T19:55:02.821529061+03:00] Could not load necessary
> modules for Conntrack: Running modprobe nf_conntrack failed with
> message: modprobe: invalid option -- 'a' BusyBox v1.31.1 (2023-04-14
> 03:02:50 CST) multi-call binary. Usage: modprobe [-rq] MODULE
> [SYMBOL=VALUE]...     -r  Remove MODULE   -q  Quiet, error: exit status 1
> INFO[2023-06-08T19:55:02.898668345+03:00] Default bridge (docker0) is
> assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be
> used to set a preferred IP address
> INFO[2023-06-08T19:55:02.916840721+03:00] Loading containers: done.
> WARN[2023-06-08T19:55:02.917174613+03:00] Could not get operating
> system name: Error opening /usr/lib/os-release: open
> /usr/lib/os-release: no such file or directory
> WARN[2023-06-08T19:55:02.917207803+03:00] Could not get operating
> system version: Error opening /usr/lib/os-release: open
> /usr/lib/os-release: no such file or directory
> INFO[2023-06-08T19:55:02.970614869+03:00] Docker daemon
> commit=42c8b31 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.22
> INFO[2023-06-08T19:55:02.970648693+03:00] Daemon has completed
> initialization           INFO[2023-06-08T19:55:02.984664788+03:00] API
> listen on /var/run/docker.sock

I can't put all outputs here, I don't know why

It was working fine, but I don't know what's wrong now. Can someone help me solve the problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pivot_root issue should be related to the ramdisk filesystem that is not a supported on `overlay2`.

So set the environemnt variable for dockerd about ramdisk:

```
DOCKER_RAMDISK=true
```

Comment: I do not know how to really thank you. Thank you very much, my friend. I apologize because I did not reply at the time that you sent me the answer, because I was unable to find the solution and left it, but now it worked. Thank you very much, my friend.

Comment: Glad to hear that my answer solved your issue! If you think was a good answer please upvote it. This is enough for me to continue to give my support whenever I can.

Comment: i'm try to upVote You Yesterday and i got this problem,
`Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.`

so iam sorry i can't